# Understanding how accessing private method is not throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

In jitsi Meet they have a method not declared in interface

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeet.m#L217

```
- (RCTBridge *)getReactBridge {
    return _bridgeWrapper.bridge;
}
```

in other file, they are accessing it like this but this isn't throwing/complaining about any error

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView.m#L200

```
 RCTBridge *bridge = [[JitsiMeet sharedInstance] getReactBridge];
        rootView
            = [[RNRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                      moduleName:@"App"
                               initialProperties:props];
        rootView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;

        // Add rootView as a subview which completely covers this one.
        [rootView setFrame:[self bounds]];
        rootView.autoresizingMask
            = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview:rootView];
```

Shouldn't xcode throw an error here? since this isn't declared in interface?

Comment: Perhaps it is declared in a category, or on a superclass?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions without accepting any answers.

Comment: @matt Sorry, Marked them answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be declared in JitsiMeet+Private.h - this looks like a Objective-C pattern where you would like to have something like 'protected' methods, and you do that by making a header file which exposes methods to friendly classes.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: Can you please explain me the code flow here? like how is it working and how they have declared it as private?

Comment: It's not private, that's just the name of the file. JitsiMeetView.m does #import "JitsiMeet+Private.h" at the top, so it can see the interfaces declared in that file. They put the 'class extension' the "@interface JitsiMeet ()" in the JitsiMeet+Private.h file, normally you see that before the implementation in the .m, but by moving it to a header, other friendly .m files can import and see it too.